# How to change Cassandra number of tokens in a node

Tags: cassandra

I am new at Cassandra, and I believe I setup all the configurations. Now after reading for a while I came across a setup article, and I found a difference between my setup and what was being explained.

Here is a Screenshot my configuration.
[image]
Now my question is, what is Tokens for? and How can I change it to 256?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the virtual nodes features, then you can set the number of tokens to a value like 256, and this will allow Cassandra to automatically load balance your data when nodes are added or removed from a cluster.

There are two fields in cassandra.yaml that control the use of virtual nodes: ".. don’t set the `initial_token` parameter in your conf/cassandra.yaml and instead enable the `num_tokens` parameter. A good default value for this is 256."  See more information [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeVnodesUsing_c.html).  You would also generally set `partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner`

If you want to change the number of virtual nodes on an existing node, you need to rebuild the data on the node.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416642/cassandra-vnodes-can-i-lower-the-number-on-slower-nodes-and-expect-rebalancing/32419325#32419325).

Comment: Thanks Jim! I started working on it, and I was able to change the seed's tokens and I am making my way towards the others. I just have one question, and I hope you can answer it. The tokens num, does it have to do anything with how fast the reads are?

Comment: As far as I know, using virtual nodes doesn't impact the read time, but I'm not sure.  I have read that using vnodes will slow down repair time since each token is repaired separately.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I will test and let you know.