# How to change num_tokoens in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I want to change `num_tokens` value in Cassandra 2.0. But If I do that, I need to delete my existing data. Otherwise it throws an error saying it can't change this configuration.

Is there a way I can do this change without deleting my existing data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the number of virtual nodes on an existing node, you need to rebuild the data on the node. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416642/cassandra-vnodes-can-i-lower-the-number-on-slower-nodes-and-expect-rebalancing/32419325#32419325).

Comment: Thanks for the reply malyy. What should I do if I have only 1 node?